# Ruby on Rails and gmap location

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, google-maps-api-3, gmaps4rails

I come here to ask you some informations or maybe help to try to do what i want.

Here it's what i want to realize:

I have a website and on it i have some places in database (with lattitude and longitude saved). I want allow users, when they click on a button, display a map with a marker on their actual position and others markers who will represent the places from the database near them.

I found some tools like [google map API v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation). With it i can show the user position but i don't know how i can display the position of the places store in my database.

If you have any ideas or examples.

Thank you.
(PS: Sorry for my english)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I built a similar app with Spring and Java.  What you'll have to do is create `Placemark` JS objects and pass them to the Google Maps API.  You can also pass a map size to determine the scope of the map returned to the user.

In order to determine nearby locations, simply build some ruby/rails code to limit the distance of locations from the user location.

1. Get user location
2. Determine which locations to show on map within your rails app
3. Pass desired placemarks to Google Maps (This can be found in API docs which are great)
4. Display the map returned by Google Maps on a view.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I get the user location, i create JS object who contains the coordinate but i can't find how display them on the map. I try to find information in the doc but i don't find how display some placemarker from database. Have you more information or link that could help me?Thanks.

Comment: Markers in the Google Maps API docs:  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers

Comment: Thanks for your help, i know how i will do.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use geocoder gem for that:
http://www.rubygeocoder.com/

Comment: That doesn't help with integration in to Google Maps.